# 64-bit kernel undefined behaviour with C calls

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, kernel, osdev

Im working on my knowledge in lower level languages, and therefore decided to try out writing a insanely minimal kernel in x86_64. Just having some problems with optimization.

My bootloader (run from GRUB) looks like this.

```
.global start
.section .text
start:
    mov $stack_top, %esp
    call kernel_main
    hlt
.size start, . - start

.section .bss
.align 16
stack_bottom:
    .space 16384
stack_top:
```

My 'kernel' does the following things.

```c
void kernel_main(void) {
    terminal_buffer = (uint16_t*) 0xB8000;
    uint16_t vga_char = ((VGA_BLACK << 4 | VGA_MAGENTA) << 8) | 'Y';
}
```

My problem is that using no optimization, the kernel_main doesn't even get called (or atleast, the behaviour within doesn't behave correctly). Im also having random off-by-one errors with the printed character, depending on what optimization i use.

I believe this could be because the processor still is in real/protected mode (GRUB ensures this), but i run C compiled with a x86_64-elf compiler. Is there a valid way to write C code for real/protected mode (i.e. 32-bit code) in a x86_64-elf compiler, so that i can write central bootup (checking long mode compat, switching to long mode, etc.). Or would i have to build another compiler? Or is this totally unreasonable, and "has" (and really should) to be done in assembly?

Comment: Sounds like you have written 64-bit code but you haven't actually put the processor into 64-bit long mode. GRUB only puts the processor into 32-bit protected mode, so you get unpredictable results when 64-bit code is run in 32-bit mode. Usually the first observation many see from this is unusual output when they write to the display as the incompatibilities of instructions become more noticeable. YOu have to write code before calling kernel_main that changes processor to 64-bit long mode.

Comment: @MichaelPetch thats what i thought. Is there some way to run a c function in 32-bit mode, and switch to long mode within c?

Comment: Switching to long mode in C isn't easy or practical. You usually write assembly code to set up paging, set up a GDT, switch to long mode and then call your kernel_main.

Comment: Thank you for the good clarification. I just prefer C overall, and saw some headers related to cpuid, and had the thought that it may be possible. Will have to dig in deeper into assembly then:)

Comment: You might be able to get some ideas from this: http://ringzeroandlower.com/2017/08/08/x86-64-kernel-boot.html . That is for Multiboot2 but the bulk of that can be easily be moved to GRUB legacy.

Comment: @Olle Just compile your code for 32 bit mode (pass `-m32`).  Setting up long mode is slightly involved, though it can be done.

Comment: @fuz Didn't work for me. I can't link a 32bit obj file (generated by c compiler) to the assembly file, as that was compiled for x86_64

Comment: @Olle Well of course you would have to use 32 bit object files for the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

a) You say you kernel is for x86-64. If you intended to compile your kernel for such, then that is your issue. GRUB does not support booting into long mode. It boots you into 32-bit x86 protected mode; not 64-bit mode. You must tell your compiler to compile for 32-bit (by passing `-m32`).

b) I don't use GAS that often, but I think you need to put `.extern kernel_main` at the top of the assembly file, under your global statement. I am unsure, however. I would try my first suggestion, and if that does not work, add the extern line.

Comment: GAS only supports `.extern` for compatibility with other assemblers. GAS effectively ignores the directive as it assumes all undefined symbols are external.